# Converting .multiple shapefiles into Image Pyramid?

Tags: openlayers-2, geoserver, shapefile, tiles

I have multiple shapefiles, and I want to import them as image tiles.

How do I convert a shapefile into image format and then convert that single image file into an image pyramid such as that of OpenStreetMap (OSM)?

I have worked with GeoServer for backend and OpenLayers to render the map but now I am asking about converting my own custom shapefiles into OSM tile pyramid.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are mixing different things:

OSM (and different other map providers, too) deliver maps as so called 'tiles' that are delivered and organized via a so called [Tile Map Service](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/TMS) standard.
You can find the specs for the URL (or folder) structures [here](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Slippy_map_tilenames).

You find different servers that support a TMS rendering. OSM itself uses Mapnik, that supports shapefiles, too. For example the coastlines are embedded just as shapefile.